# How to Transform a href to submit button in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8:

```
<a href ="{{ route('post.selfreview.all')}}" class="{{ (! $goals->pluck('employee_mid_year_comment')->contains(null)) ? '' : 'disabled' }} btn btn-primary float-left"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Submit</a>
```

That disables  a href   until when there is no null  employee_mid_year_comment fields

How do I transform the same code for submit button shown below?

```
<form  action="{{ route('post.selfreview.all'" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Submit</button>   
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a class on the button, you can use same ternary condition to add `disabled` property to your button, like this:

```
<form  action="{{ route('post.selfreview.all'" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" {{ (! $goals->pluck('employee_mid_year_comment')->contains(null)) ? '' : 'disabled' }}> <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Submit</button>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As any Button has a `disabled` attribute all you can do is

```
<form  action="{{ route('post.selfreview.all'" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" {{ (! $goals->pluck('employee_mid_year_comment')->contains(null)) ? '' : 'disabled' }}> <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Submit</button>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add disabled attribute in button

```
<button {{ (! $goals->pluck('employee_mid_year_comment')->contains(null)) ? '' : 'disabled' }} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> 
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Submit
</button>
```